# making a fully fledged online syncronized star rating system

Tags: iphone

does anyone know how its possible to make a rating system that updates across all application downloads based on other users input. i would preferably like to use this framwork if possible
http://code.google.com/p/agautam-code/source/browse/trunk/iPhone/?r=7#iPhone/RatingView.
is this even possible in objective c?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking someone to just give you the code, you're out of luck - it's too big a question for that ;)

To communicate between downloaded apps you will need some sort of sever holding the rating. Then, when a user changes a rating on their app it will pass the rating back to the server and store it there.

Then, while each app is running it will check the server for new ratings and download them. When it's got the latest ratings from the server it will update the UI (using the RatingView you mentioned in your question if you want).

Personally, I'd use the [ASI libraries](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for the iPhone communication and Ruby on Rails for the server part. Both ASI and RoR are very easy to use and there are lots of ruby on rails webhosts out there to host your server for you.

However, you can use whatever you like really, it's up to you.

Sam